# Rules for toggling bool variables C++

Tags: c++

I was wondering if there is some kind of a mechanism in C++ that allow me to automatically togle other bool variables when I set one e.g: If I have something like that:

```
bool first=true;
bool second =false;
bool third=false;
```

Then if I need to have:

```
first =false;
second=false;
third =true;
```

Is there any thing that allows to to change the state of only one bool variable and automatically changes (or keeps) states of other bool variables according to any rule ?

Comment: Yes, keep them as private member and write a method that changes them

Comment: Note: Once you require a set of `bool` variables, consider using bit-masking instead.

Comment: You simply want to write a function to do that.

Comment: If you have several mutally exclusive states, use an enum and name them.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to use functions for doing that. The bit-masking seems to be really great solution. Thanks a lot !

Comment: I hope you intend to use `std::bitset` instead of manual bit masking all over the code. If the states are mutually exclusive I would strongly recommend to use an `enum class` instead.